# Level Of Details for visual graph

Tags: graph

I have an application that visualize network data structure as visual graph of nodes and links.
Because the network can be very big the interactivity of the visual graph is damaged.
I would like to use some kind of Level Of Detail algorithm to lower the number of nodes and links I present when the zoom factor is very far from the normal zoom (that is when the nodes looks like tiny dots).

I've found lost of information about 3D LOD but nothing about 2D or more specifically LOD in 2D graph.

Any help will be great.

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work? [An LOD Model for Graph Visualization and its Application  in Web Navigation](http://domino.research.ibm.com/comm/research_teams.nsf/pages/iva.publications.html/%24FILE/graph%20visualization-lod-apweb05.pdf)